# Fancybox 2 + CSS - classes not pulling through

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Although familiar with fancybox having used successfully a number of times before, i've run into a problem - it fires normally as it should, the large image appears and grouped as I intended..but no CSS styling at all.

The script and css are included as they should be (I have double checked, but you never know..) and when you click on the thumbnail, the large images appears centred, then shifts to the right.

It appears that none of the CSS classes are being applied to the fancybox elements, possibly causing the shifting to the right? As well the lack of styling obviously. Looking at the styling info via web toolbar of what should be the image inside fancybox wrap, just shows the following:

```
html > div > div > div..etc.. > img
```

I'm no javascript expert, so apologies if I'm just being dense- i've done a fair bit of searching for similiar questions but no luck.

Link: http://www.tom-mayfield.com/angelcakes/?what-we-do/weddings.html

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Comment: Are you sure that the CSS rules are being loaded into the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the fancybox css file is there, however the fancybox css settings are not applied to the box, why?

You are loading your fancybox css like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tom-mayfield.com/angelcakes/public/scripts/fancybox2/jquery.fancybox.css" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

**BUT** if you set this attribute :

```
media="print"
```

... it means that fancybox styles will be applied only when (and if) you print your document, which doesn't really make sense, does it?.

Just change `media="print"` to `media="screen"`

Comment: Oh my...no, fancybox probably won't print too well!! Thanks, job done.